# How to find every point [ coordinates ] between two geolocation coordinates?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, math, leaflet, latitude-longitude

**Leaflet map**

[image: map]

How i get geo-coordinates( i.e latitude,longitude ) on every 1km/2km/(n)Km between two geolocation points. Image above for reference.

Comment: You cannot get every coordinate between two points - life is too short to retrieve **infinite** number of points. Probably you need SLERP - spherical linear interpolation to get needed number of points between A and B ends. Don't know whether used map frameworks contain any function for this.

Answer (score 3):

The "right way" to do this is to use [geographiclib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/other.html) to fetch the azimuth and angular distance between the points; then fetch intermediate points by keeping the azimuth but specifying a different angular distance.

Geographiclib is also able to calculate a point given an initial point, an azimuth, and a distance in meters.

I suggest you first do a bit of research on what a "great circle" is, as well as the [direct and inverse geodetic problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid).