# latitude and longitude on mapbox using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

Using leaflet,  a line is constructed between 2 points with known coordinates of end points.
how can we get latitude and longitude of all points lying on that line.

Comment: Did you try linear algebra?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find every point \[ coordinates \] between two geolocation coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096257/how-to-find-every-point-coordinates-between-two-geolocation-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

As I said already in [How to find every point [ coordinates ] between two geolocation coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096257/how-to-find-every-point-coordinates-between-two-geolocation-coordinates/37100843#37100843), the right way is to use [geographiclib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/other.html) to fetch the azimuth and distance between points, and calculate new points using the same azimuth but different distances, and do research about great circles.

If you don't care about great circles and prefer to fetch the lat-lngs of the straight line as displayed in EPSG:3857, then use [`map.project`, `map.unproject`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-conversion-methods) and a tiny bit of linear interpolation.